# Forcing www using .htaccess not working as expected

Tags: .htaccess, hosting, cpanel

I want my domain, theatrenearyou.org, to automatically redirect to www.theatrenearyou.org. I have a .htaccess file in my site's root directory along with some html files, but when I visit https://theatrenearyou.org it does not redirect to https://www.theatrenearyou.org

I'm using InMotionHosting, and I've made sure my .htaccess file is being read by testing out some redirects such as redirecting /pizza to /about.html. It seems like the .htaccess file is being read, but for some reason no matter what I do I cannot get it to force www.

This is what I currently have in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This should redirect to https://www.theatrenearyou.org but instead the URL remains at https://theatrenearyou.org.

Comment: Could it be that you are looking at cached results? Try an anonymous browser window...

Comment: Also you need to make sure that it is not your hosting provider that actually _removes_ the (unnecessary) "www." prefix by rewriting...